# Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Numerics.Vectors" that could not be resolved

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, system.numerics.vectors

I have a Xamarin app, targeting  Android SDK 30, and every time I compile the project, I get this warning:

```
Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Numerics.Vectors" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
    "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
    References which depend on "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll].
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll".
            System.Numerics.Vectors
    References which depend on "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [].
        C:\Users\itsve\.nuget\packages\system.text.json\5.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Json.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\itsve\.nuget\packages\system.text.json\5.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Json.dll".
            C:\Users\itsve\.nuget\packages\system.text.json\5.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Json.dll
            D:\Repos\MyApp\MyApp.Services\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\MyApp.Services.dll
            D:\Repos\MyApp\MyApp\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\MyApp.dll
            C:\Users\itsve\.nuget\packages\identitymodel\5.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\IdentityModel.dll
            C:\Users\itsve\.nuget\packages\prism.plugin.logging.common\8.0.11-beta\lib\monoandroid10.0\Prism.Plugin.Logging.Common.dll
            C:\Users\itsve\.nuget\packages\refit\5.2.4\lib\netstandard2.1\Refit.dll
            C:\Users\itsve\.nuget\packages\MyApp.auth.apiclient\2021.9.27.1\lib\netstandard2.0\MyApp.Auth.ApiClient.dll
            C:\Users\itsve\.nuget\packages\MyApp.budgeting.apiclient\2021.10.7.2\lib\netstandard2.0\MyApp.Budgeting.ApiClient.dll   MyApp.Android
```

The project doesn't reference neither `System.Numerics.Vectors` nor `System.Numerics`.
How to fix this? It's not even clear to me what is causing the issue..

---

Update: I registered it as a bug of Xamarin.Forms - https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15046

Comment: Does this issue occure on each project? When you create a new project, do you get the same issue?

Comment: The "clean" project doesn't have this issue, but once I add `identitymodel@5.x` or `prism.plugin.logging.common@8.x` or `identitymodel@5.x` and do "Rebuild" -> I immediately get this warning.

Comment: When you add the identitymodel, prism.plugin.logging.common. The  System.Numerics.Vectors has two diferent versions to make the conflict. Try to update with the same version of System.Numerics.Vectors.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT, the problem is that `MonoAndroid\v1.0` is referencing the OLD version of this library. I have no idea how to upgrade that. It seems to be a bug in Xamarin, what do you think?

Comment: Have you try to update the Xamarin.Forms? It would update the MonoAndroid as well.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT, no, we use the latest version of Xamarin.Forms - 5.0.0.2244.

Answer (score 0):

Under the iOS and Android projects, expand References, and remove the `System.Numerics` and `System.Numerics.Vectors` references if they exist. Rebuild and the errors should go away.

These references (which point to version 2.0.5.0) seem to have been added by the VS Xamarin.Forms template, which conflict with the version referenced by the newer Nuget packages.

Comment: No, the project doesn't have any references to these libraries. I'll also add this information to the post